# How to get value from URL in Sandbox solution of Office 365 (SharePoint Online)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I have created custom webpart and deployed on default edit page. now i wnt to access the ListItem ID from the Page URL but it gives error that you can not use request.Query String in Office 365.

How can i access ID from URL ? is there any option to access this?
Reply as soon as possible ....

Comment: are u using like this HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["String"];

Comment: I have used HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["String"]; and Page.Request.QueryString["String"] but both are not working. do you have any option to access url in sharepoint online ?

Comment: when i used HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["String"]; that give the null value

Comment: there is querystring in url?

Comment: Yes, it is "ID"  and i want to get value of that ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What error are you getting exactly? I have used

```
string sourceID = Convert.ToString(Page.Request.QueryString["ID"]);
```

in Office365/SharePoint Online successfully without getting any error.

Also, I see that you have passed "String" inside the square brackets instead of "ID". Could that be an issue? You need to pass the exact name of parameter you want the value of.